# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined at geoLocationInit

Tags: javascript

I get the following error when trying to obtain the current location of the user, This is what displays in my console

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined
>       at geoLocationInit (google.js:8)
>       at HTMLDocument. (google.js:5)
>       at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>       at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

```
var map;
var myLatLng;
$(document).ready(function() {
    geoLocationInit();

    function geoLocationInit() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geoLocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
        } else {
            alert("Browser not supported");
        }
    }

    function success(position) {
        console.log(position);
        var Latval = position.coords.latitude;
        var Lngval = position.coords.longitude;
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latval, Lngval);
        createMap(myLatLng);
    }

    function fail() {
        alert("It Failed");
    }
    //Create Map
    function createMap(myLatLng) {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.3285284, 32.5738946);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 12
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
        });
    }

    //Create marker
    function createMarker(LatLng, icn, name) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: icn,
            title: name
        });
    }

    //Nearby search
    function nearbySearch(myLatLng, type) {
        var request = {
            location: myLatLng,
            radius: '1500',
            types: [type]
        };
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

        function callback(results, status) {
            //console.log(results);
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var place = results[i];
                    LatLng = place.geometry.location;
                    icn = place.icon;
                    name = place.name;
                    createMarker(LatLng, icn, name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `navigator.geoLocation.getCurrentPosition` to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

Comment: Thanx alot Yusuf